# What is /?jb-disable-modules=all used for in a url?

Tags: wordpress

Someone went to my website and according to google analytics they went to "url.com"/?jb-disable-modules=all. Is this an attempt to hack my website?

Saw this in google analytics. I am using wordpress and plugins, no direct coding.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from JetPack. You are safe.
If you have any of the JetPack optimization tools running, it sends a visit to scan the website in order to score it.